# Restore Search service on different Server or Farm , with different topology

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, restore

We have a SharePoint 2016 on-prem Search Farm as below

Our production farm has 2 pairs of search servers with 2 search indexers / query processors & 2 crawlers
Our test environement farm has one (01) search server

[image]

how we can retore the search service in the test environnement , from the production farm , Knowing that we tried that but we got the following error :

- InvalidTopologyException: Could not find a valid server in the farm with server name :
- The specified component exists. You must specify a name that does not exist.
- Aborted due to error in another component.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to backup search databases in SQL server of your Prod environment then restore them in the SQL server of your test environment.

After that, restore Search service application with using the existing databases.

More information, you can refer to:
[SharePoint 2013 – Restore Search Service Application on different Server or Farm](http://blog.harter-web.de/2017/03/22/sharepoint-2013-restore-search-service-application-different-server-farm/)

Comment: Thank's Kally i confirm that the problem is resolved , i changed the search topology in the production environnement, before running an new backup operation. the restoration phase worked well now. Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You only need the Admin DB. So you should only restore the one database. (singular) Performing the restore does not recreate the previous topology, you still have to do that in a second step.